# Git bundle - What files are inside?

Tags: git

I am working on a project where after creating a git bundle I need to generate a list of metadata for files that are part of the bundle.

For example, if a git repo has 50 commits and my git bundle consists of changes for the last two commits, I need to generate metadata (i.e., filename, filetype, size etc) for all the git repository files that are part of the bundle. I do not want to include information about any files that git generates only for its internal representation. Could you please suggest a convenient way of doing it? Thanks

Git bundle creation:

```
git bundle create mybundle -2 master
```

Fetching from the bundle:

```
git fetch mybundle master:localRef
```

Generate a list of files that are part of the bundle:

```
??
```

Comment: From Git point of view a bundle is a remote repository. Git doesn't have commands to list files at the remote repositories. To list files you need to clone/fetch commits from the remote repository including the bundle.

Comment: How do you want to show deleted files? Say the bundle contains 2 commits. Commit 1 adds a file, commit 2 modifies the file, commit 3 deletes the file. Should the (deleted) file be listed by your command? Or are you only interested in the tree of the last commit in the bundle?

Answer (score 1):

A version 3 Git bundle looks like this:

```
# v3 git bundle
@object-format=sha1
-2e8e77cbac8ac17f94eee2087187fa1718e38b14 The twenty-first batch
404bf1f83ac4b2fd270825f18274d88293dd80bd HEAD

PACK...
```

In other words, it contains a header, capabilities, a list of requirements (prefixed with `-`), and the revisions it includes, followed by a pack file.  (Version 2 bundles are similar but lack capabilities.)  Either in the original repository, or once you've pulled the bundle in, you can use `git rev-list` to see all of the objects using a syntax like `git rev-list --objects 404bf1f83ac4b2fd270825f18274d88293dd80bd --not 2e8e77cbac8ac17f94eee2087187fa1718e38b14`.  That will provide you the objects that are sent, but not the file names.

If you want the file names, it becomes trickier.  You can do a `git diff --names-only` or `git diff --raw` between each of the old and new revisions (that is, at each separate commit) and see what's included.  However, that doesn't necessarily tell you whether the object for a file is included in the bundle, since if Git already knows that the existing data has blob `abc123` and it's required for the new revision as well, it won't be included since it's unnecessary.

Once you have that data, you can use `git cat-file --batch-check='%(objectname) %(objectsize) %(objecttype)'` to get the type and size for the particular revision.

However, I will warn you that in general, what you want to do is nontrivial because Git will often optimize out data that it doesn't need to send, and so while you can know what objects are *referenced*, as I mentioned above, that doesn't mean that they're actually *included* in the pack.  You may need to filter out objects that don't appear in the `git rev-list` output if you really want to exclude them altogether.

It's pretty difficult to do this at all without pulling the data in from the bundle into a repository with suitable dependencies without reimplementing the Git pack format, so you're going to need some repository to do this work in.